# PowerShell output and formatting

Tags: powershell

I have something I have put together to scan computers on my network and look for certain chrome extensions.

It works and displays the information in the PowerShell console. But if it finds the extension in **multiple** user profiles on a machine it creates a giant blob of information instead of separating it into multiple lines and I would like to have this output to a txt or csv file:

```
$hostnamestxt = "Server with list of computers"
$computers = get-content “$hostnamestxt”

write-host Scanning........


foreach($computer in $computers){
$BetterNet = "\\$computer\c$\users\*\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\gjknjjomckknofjidppipffbpoekiipm"

 if (Test-Path $BetterNet) {
    $a = Get-ChildItem $BetterNet
    write-host BetterNet found on: 
    Write-Host "     "$a 
    write-host 
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to *enumerate* the return value of the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem $BetterNet | ForEach-Object {
    write-host BetterNet found on: 
    Write-Host "     "$_ 
    write-host 
}
```

Comment: This works great at breaking up the blobs of data. Thank you very much. how about outputting it to a file?

Comment: Instead of using the `Write-Host` cmdlet, take a look at `Set-Content` and the `Add-Content` cmdlet. Be carefull about the encoding (`-Encodign` parameter)